# Separating the complements of two sets in each other

Tags: general-topology

Let $U,V\subseteq \mathbf R^n$ be open sets with non-empty intersection.

> Do there exist disjoint open sets $A,B\subseteq U\cup V$ such that $U\setminus V\subseteq A$ and $V\setminus U\subseteq B$?

Drawing pictures and taking intuition from $\mathbf R^1$ and $\mathbf R^2$ it seems that the answer should "obviously" be yes, by splitting $U\cap V$ "down the middle" by a closed set, then taking the two pieces and adding them to $U\setminus V$ and $V\setminus U$, respectively (see picture below). This is "oviously" not a proof, so I was hoping someone could help me with the right terminology here.

Unfortunately the closures of $U\setminus V$ and $V\setminus U$ intersect, so I can't use the fact that any two non-intersecting closed sets are separable. However $\overline{U\setminus V}\cap V\setminus U = \emptyset$ and $\overline{V\setminus U}\cap U\setminus V = \emptyset$, but I'm not sure if this helps.

[image]

**Hour later edit:**

I think I worked it out, maybe someone can spot an error in my attempt. Let $W := \overline {U\cap V} \cap (U\cup V)$, which is closed in $U\cup V$. Note that
\begin{align*}
U' & := (U\setminus V)\setminus \text{int}(U\setminus V) \subseteq W \text{ is closed,} \\
V' & := (V\setminus U)\setminus \text{int}(V\setminus U) \subseteq W \text{ is closed,}
\end{align*}
and moreover $U'\cap V' = \emptyset$. Hence there exist open sets $U'',V''\subseteq W$ (open in $W$) with $U'\subseteq U''$, $V'\subseteq V''$ and $U''\cap V'' = \emptyset$. Then $(U'')^c, (V'')^c$ are both closed in $W$, so $(U'')^c\cap W, (V'')^c\cap W$ are both closed in $U\cup V$. Since $U\setminus V$, $V\setminus U$ are both closed in $U\cup V$, we have that
\begin{align*}
A & := \left(((U'')^c \cap W) \cup (V\setminus U)\right)^c ,\\
B & := \left(((V'')^c \cap W) \cup (U\setminus V)\right)^c ,
\end{align*}
are both open in $U\cup V$, with $U\setminus V \subseteq A$ and $V\setminus U \subseteq B$, and most importantly, $A\cap B = \emptyset.$

Comment: An idea might be to use the fact that $U-\overline{V}$ and $V-\overline{U}$ are open, so take tiny open balls around the points of $\overline{V}$ and $\overline{U}$ to create $A$ and $B$ resp.

Comment: @SantanaAfton Maybe that works, I'm not quite sure - I am worried though that any open ball around a point of $\overline U\cap \overline V$ immediately contains points of both $U$ and $V$. Either way, I've edited my question with a possible solution using a different approach.

Comment: Why can you find $U'' \subset U'$ open in $W$?

Comment: @klirk I assume you mean $U'\subset U''$ - this is true because every pair of disjoint closed sets have disjoint open neighborhoods in $\mathbf R^n$. This is being a "normal space" (or having the T4 axiom), and is one step weaker than the T5 axiom in William's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces with the property for all A,B, $\overline A \cap B$ and $A \cap \overline B$ are empty implies A and B are separated by open sets are called completely normal.

As $R^n$ is completely normal your proof will work and can be generalized to completely normal spaces.

Comment: Yes, seems like it's called the "[T5 axiom](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:T5_Space)" sometimes, exactly what I need.